# Datadog dashboard for "time since thing last completed"

Tags: datadog

Using Datadog Events or custom metrics how does one create a dashboard showing "Time since some thing last completed" ?  Is this possible?

So if the thing I'm monitoring completed hourly, EXCEPT at 11a and 4p, the chart would look like

[image: since-last-completed-time-sample]

I was able to do this with a big tech monitoring system & the charts were useful (eg an alerting threshold is a red horizontal line that the sawtooth creeps up towards)